# Refresh widget every minute

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

How I can refresh my widget every minute?
Is this a right way to do it?

`let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: currentDate)`

Or do I need to create entries until the next midnight? Like this:

```
let currentDate = Date()
let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: currentDate)
let nextMidnight = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: midnight)!

    for offset in 0 ..< 60 * 24 {
        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: offset, to: midnight)!
        entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: entryDate))
        }

  let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(nextMidnight))
  completion(timeline)
    }
```

My question is: what is the difference between these two methods?

I mean, in the first method we say that we want to refresh widget every minute, and in the second we create entries for every minute until the next midnight? Why? Can't we just do it like in the first method?

Thank you.

Comment: Widgets have limits on how many times they can be refreshed. I think I read somewhere that it was a max of 70 a day but Apple is free to limit that amount if the user isn't looking at your widget or using it. Try the Widget Code Along they talk about all this.

Comment: @loremipsum Yeah, I finally got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A widget’s budget applies to a 24-hour period. WidgetKit tunes the 24-hour window to the user’s daily usage pattern, which means the daily budget doesn’t necessarily reset at exactly midnight. For a widget the user frequently views, a daily budget typically includes from 40 to 70 refreshes. This rate roughly translates to widget reloads every 15 to 60 minutes, but it’s common for these intervals to vary due to the many factors involved.

Here you can read and find the answer to your question. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date